# Update a table on different database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, cross-database

How can I update a table on another database without giving a direct permissions on that table to the current database user?

Without using **Execute As Owner** because it requires **Trustworthy** to be on for the database and it is not recommended to use it.

Comment: Do you have a linked server connection that you can use?

Comment: The two databases are on the same instance

Comment: It is probably best to just dial in the permissions directly to the user / SQL account that is going to be doing the write, otherwise you would have to give that user / SQL account a higher permission that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You do this using cross database certificates.  See [here for an example](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/using-certificates-for-cross-database-access/).